# Why does this program give different outputs on ubuntu windows desktop app and on ubuntu virtual box?

Tags: c, ubuntu, signals, fcntl

The program is basically checking for how fcntl function works. The main program(Pm.c) creates a pipe and 3 child processes by forking. It then does necessary fcntl function on the pipe and then writes to it.
The child processes terminate after receiving the signal from pipe in ubuntu virtual box but they don't receive any signal in the ubuntu windows app.

Pm.c -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main()
{
    int c = getpid(), c1, c2, c3;
    int pp[2];
    pipe(pp);
    char *args[1];
    args[0] = NULL;

    if((c1 = fork()) == 0)
        execvp("./p1", args);
    if((c2 = fork()) == 0)
        execvp("./p2", args);
    if((c3 = fork()) == 0)
        execvp("./p3", args);

    setpgid(0, 0);
    setpgid(c1, c);
    setpgid(c2, c);
    setpgid(c3, c);

    printf("%d %d %d %d\n", c, c1, c2, c3);
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n", getpgid(c), getpgid(c1), getpgid(c2), getpgid(c3));
    int gid = getpgid(c);

    sleep(1);

    fcntl(pp[0], F_SETFL, O_ASYNC);
    fcntl(pp[0], __F_SETSIG, SIGUSR1);
    fcntl(pp[0], F_SETOWN, -gid);

    write(pp[1], "bruh ", 4);
    close(pp[1]);
    wait(NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

P1.c (P2.c and P3.c is similar to this)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

int pr = 1;

void hdfn(int x)
{
    printf("Recieved signal from pm\n");
    pr--;
}

int main()
{
    signal(SIGUSR1, hdfn);
    printf("P1 is running\n");
    while(pr);
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output in Ubuntu virtual Box. The program terminates and is the correct output -

```
1846 1847 1848 1849
1846 1846 1846 1846
P1 is running
P2 is running
P3 is running
Recieved signal from pm
Recieved signal from pm
Recieved signal from pm
User defined signal 1
```

output on ubuntu windows app. (Program doesn't terminate) -

```
26 27 28 29
26 26 26 26
P1 is running
P2 is running
P3 is running
```

Can someone please tell why there's a difference in output and how I can get the correct output on ubuntu app.

Comment: `while(pr);` can be optimised out. You'll _at least_ need `volatile` Also: you cannot use `printf()` in a signal handler.

Comment: regarding: `execvp("./p1", args);`   1)  The `args[]` parameter needs (at least) 3 entries. [0] = "./p1"  [1] = "p1" [2] = NULL.  2) the next statement should be: `perror( "execvp for p1 failed" );` followed by `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: when calling the function: `fork()` there are three conditions to check for:: 1) >0 indicates in parent process.  ==0 indicates in child process.  <0 indicates and error occurred.

Comment: the function: `fork()` returns a `pid_t`  (which current is an 'int' however, that is not guaranteed

Comment: the function: `getpgid()` returns a `pid_t`, not necessarily a `int`

Comment: regarding: `wait(NULL);`  Need to call `wait()` or `waitpid()` for each child process, not just one of them

Comment: regarding: `printf("Recieved signal from pm\n");`  (BTW: Received)  the function `printf()` is not 'safe' to use in a signal handler.  Suggest:  `write( 1, "Recieved signal from pm\n", sizeof( "Recieved signal from pm\n" ) );`

Comment: why run the same pipe to three different child processes?  This results in a race condition as to which child process will see the data placed on the pipe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `fcntl` doesn't exist on windows subsystem for linux. I'd expect your "ubuntu windows app" is [this app](http://%20https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu/9nblggh4msv6?activetab=pivot:overviewtab). Your code is compiling because headers exist but `fcntl` is not supported. See this [github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/601).

Comment: but then how would it be compiling properly then?

Comment: @RishiJS Please accept if this answers your question.

Comment: Can you tell me what else isnt available on windows subsystem for linux please?

Comment: @RishiJS Please accept it, if this answers your question. It'll help future readers like you.